# Go xml unmarshalling

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

Is there a way to extract the source of an image in an HTML file using only one struct (with `encode/xml`)? Now I have something like this

```go
type XML struct {
    A Image `xml:"div>img"`
}

type Image struct {
    I string `xml:"src,attr"`
}
```

And would be great to only declare something like this :

```go
type Image struct {
    I string `xml:"div>img,src,attr"`
}
```

This is the HTML :

```
<div><div><img src="hello.png"/></div></div>
```

Comment: Practically No as HTML is not XML and in real HTML parser must cope with HTML bugs. But XML does not allow bugs and XML is not HTML <img src="hello.png"> is not valid in XML as there is no </img> tag or <img src="hello.png" />

Comment: Well truth is that's a typo, now it's corrected (thank you for pointing this out). The question still remains the same.

Comment: This issue discusses exactly that for Go 1.2:
https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that a good way is to use the `exp/html` package, like this:

```go
package main

import (
    "exp/html"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    a, _ := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(testString))
    println(a.FirstChild.FirstChild.NextSibling.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.Attr[0].Val)
}

var testString = `<div><div><img src="hello.png"/></div></div>`
```

All this `FirstChild` and `NextSibling` are needed because `exp/html` constructs a "correct" html5 tree so this code is actually parsing this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <img src="hello.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```